# piping with grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I want to search "C" in the grades column inside the file "input.csv":

```
roll,name,total,rank,grade 
001,A B,78,23,C 
003,F YZ,100,1,*
```

and what I'm trying is:

```
cut -d"," -f4 input.csv | grep "C"
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Looks to me like column 5 has the C, not column 4

Answer (score 1):

Here grade is in 5th column of file, so following awk will give you expected results:

```
awk -F, 'toupper($5)=="C"' input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep ,C$ <in >out
```

...is too short to be accepted without this bit.

Comment: Quoting the regex might be handy if any shells get frisky with any metacharacters present in the unquoted regex.

Comment: @thirig - there are no characters which might cause them to be frisky here.